# Sencha touch selectfield list scroll issue

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have created toolbar containing 1 selectfield.
Items in select field are more & there is no way to know that there is more item in the list.
How can i solve this problem. Please help me.
Here is code

```
    items: [
        {
           xtype : 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            id: 'toptool',
            flex: 1,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    name: 'test',

                    options: [
                        {
                            text: 'cat 1',
                            value: '1',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 2',
                            value: '2',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 3',
                            value: '3',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 1',
                            value: '1',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 2',
                            value: '2',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 3',
                            value: '3',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 1',
                            value: '1',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 2',
                            value: '2',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 3',
                            value: '3',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 1',
                            value: '1',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 2',
                            value: '2',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 3',
                            value: '3',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 1',
                            value: '1',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 2',
                            value: '2',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cat 3',
                            value: '3',
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
                    }
       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

first off all remove the comma(,) after the "value" parameter. Now use a css class or inline style to fix the height of the select field.

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
name: 'test',
style: 'height:100px',
```